# How to get e.parameter.array() in doGet(e) funtion in Google app script while submitting an array via HTML Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-email, forms

I am trying to submit Html form with an array to google app script webapp but unable to retrieve array into the app.

here the html form code

```
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Send Mail").addItem("Insurance Mail", "insuranceMail").addToUi();
}

function insuranceMail(){
  var webApp = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwsAlL2GWySwmkGooucVmDXTJK60TLAcAgQWYAdxGumgdI2Kjs/exec";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var clientName = sh.getRange("A"+row).getDisplayValue();
  var senderID = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var clientID = sh.getRange("B"+row).getDisplayValue();
  var senderName = sh.getRange("C"+row).getDisplayValue();
  var namesOfIns = sh.getRange("D"+row).getDisplayValue().replace(/,/g,"<br>"); //Next Line Formatting
  var sub= "Additional Credentialing Options";
  var message = "";
  var date = new Date();
  var iSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Insurances");
  var iLastRow = iSheet.getLastRow();
  var insurances = [];
  var plan = [];
  var values = [];
  var tableRows = [];
  var j,count = 1,tableRow;

  for(var i = 0;i<=iLastRow;i++){
    j=i+2;
    insurances[i] = iSheet.getRange("A"+j).getDisplayValue();  //Get Insurance Names
  }
  for(var i = 0;i<=iLastRow;i++){
    j=i+2;
    plan[i] = iSheet.getRange("B"+j).getDisplayValue();  //Get Plan Names
  }
  for(var i = 0;i<=iLastRow;i++){
    j=i+2;
    values[i] = iSheet.getRange("C"+j).getDisplayValue(); // Get Yes/No values
  }

  var messageHtmlTop = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>"
  +"<style> table{font-size:11px;font-family:sans-serif;} tr,td {padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;text-align:center;}</style></head>"
  +"<body>"
  +"Hello "+clientName+",<br><br>"
  +"<br><br>"
  +"Some Html"
  +"<b>"+namesOfIns+"</b><br><br>";

  var messageHtmlTop2 = "<form action ='"+webApp+"'method='GET'><input type='email' name='clientID' value='"+clientID+"' style='display: none'><input type='text' name='clientName' value='"+clientName+"' style='display: none'>"
  +"<table><tr><th>Sr. No.</th><th>Select</th><th>Insurance</th><th>Plane</th></tr>";

  var messageHtmlMid = "";

  for(n in insurances){
    if(values[n] == "Yes" || values[n] == "yes"){
      tableRow ="<tr>"
      +"<td>"+count+"</td>"
      +"<td><input type='checkbox' name='insurances[]' value='"+insurances[n]+"'></td>"
      +"<td>"+insurances[n]+"</td>"
      +"<td>"+plan[n]+"</td>"
      +"</tr>";
      tableRows[n] = tableRow;
      count++;
    }  // Creat table rows array
  } //Add Form top to the HTML on if atleast 1 Yes is present
  for(n in tableRows){
    messageHtmlMid = messageHtmlMid.concat(tableRows[n]); //Compose HTML Form Mid Part
  };

  var messageHtmlBottom1 ="<tr></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td><input type='submit' value='Send' width=100% hieght=40px></td></tr></table>"
  +"</form><br><br>"
  +"some sentence<br><br>"

  var messageHtmlBottom ="some HTML"
  +"</body>"
  +"</html>";

  for(n in values){
    if (values[n] == 'Yes'){
      messageHtmlTop = messageHtmlTop.concat(messageHtmlTop2);
      messageHtmlBottom = messageHtmlBottom1.concat(messageHtmlBottom);
      break;
    }
  } ////Add Form bottom to the HTML on if atleast 1 Yes is present

  var messageHtml = messageHtmlTop.concat(messageHtmlMid).concat(messageHtmlBottom); //Compose Full HTML with Form

  Logger.log(messageHtml);
  try{
    MailApp.sendEmail(clientID,sub,message,{'htmlBody':messageHtml});
    sh.getRange("E"+row).setValue("Sent");
  } catch(e){
    sh.getRange("E"+row).setValue("Error");
  }
  sh.getRange("F"+row).setValue(date);
}
```

Here my webapp code i am trying to work which is giving me empty result.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var name = e.parameter.clientName;
  var id = e.parameter.clientID;
  var date = new Date();
  var iSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Responses");
  var lastRow = iSheet.getLastRow();
  var getIns =[];
  var insurances = "";

  for(n in e.parameter.insurances){
    getIns[n] = e.parameter.insurances[n];
  }
  for(n in getIns){
    insurances = insurances.concat(getIns[n]+"\n");
  }

  lastRow++;
  iSheet.getRange("A"+lastRow).setValue(name);
  iSheet.getRange("B"+lastRow).setValue(id);
  iSheet.getRange("C"+lastRow).setValue(insurances);
  iSheet.getRange("D"+lastRow).setValue(date);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Some Sentence').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)
}
```

I am getting client name,client ID,date printed into the sheet but the Column C is coming empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons you get an empty entry into the spreadsheet.

1. In the form, checkboxes are named as `insurances[]`. However, in the web app you refer to them as just `insurances`. So, please modify your Html so that the checkboxes are named  `'insurances'`

   ```
   +"<td><input type='checkbox' name='insurances' value='"+insurances[n]+"'></td>"
   ```
2. As mentioned in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) . The `e.parameter` only retrieves the first key:value pair

   > An object of key/value pairs that correspond to the request parameters. Only the first value is returned for parameters that have multiple values.

Instead, use `e.parameters`. Note the 's' at the end, it will return an array of checkbox values that were checked. As mentioned in the documentation above.

So instead of the following:

```
for(n in e.parameter.insurances){
    getIns[n] = e.parameter.insurances[n];
  }
  for(n in getIns){
    insurances = insurances.concat(getIns[n]+"\n");
  }
```

you can just do this

```
var insurances = e.parameters.insurances.join("\n")
```

Your final web app would be the following:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var name = e.parameter.clientName;
  var id = e.parameter.clientID;
  var date = new Date();
  var iSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Responses");
  var lastRow = iSheet.getLastRow();
  var getIns =[];
  var insurances = e.parameters.insurances.join("\n")
  lastRow++;
  iSheet.getRange("A"+lastRow).setValue(name);
  iSheet.getRange("B"+lastRow).setValue(id);
  iSheet.getRange("C"+lastRow).setValue(insurances);
  iSheet.getRange("D"+lastRow).setValue(date);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput('We have received your request').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)
}
```

**Final note:** Make sure to update your web app and redeploy.

References:

- [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Thank you so much, Its worked. I was missing that parameters while reading documentation.